# PHP + MySQL Display Value from multiple rows in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have always found here the solution to my troubles, but this time I really don't know how to search for what I need, then I will post here hope (but I'm sure) some one can help me make this query working.

I'm the developer of real rally (A Richard Burns Rally Mod bla bla bla).
We need now an automated system to display the final standing for each championship.

I have acquired all the necessary info from 16 queries and stored all them into a temp db.

this means I have for each championship (Montecarlo, Sweden, Mexico and so on)
15 results inside the temp table.
15 for montecarlo
15 for sweden
and so on

then I run this query

```
SELECT Id, totale, num_prove, IdPilota, Nome, Cognome, Team, Nazionalita, Plate, Classe, VetturaUsata, Penalita, PaPenalty, PuntiCarriera, PuntiCarrieraP,
PuntiMon, PuntiSve, PuntiMes, PuntiArg, PuntiPor, PuntiIta, PuntiPol, PuntiFin, PuntiGer, PuntiCin, PuntiFra, PuntiSpa, PuntiGrb, PuntiAus, RallyCorso,
SUM(PuntiMon) + SUM(PuntiSve) + SUM(PuntiMes) + SUM(PuntiArg) + SUM(PuntiPor) + SUM(PuntiIta) + SUM(PuntiPol) + SUM(PuntiFin) + SUM(PuntiGer) + SUM(PuntiCin) + SUM(PuntiFra) + SUM(PuntiSpa) + SUM(PuntiGrb) + SUM(PuntiAus) AS Punti
FROM temp_table_5975a9e73a835
GROUP BY IdPilota
ORDER BY Punti DESC;
```

now the what's wrong.
This query works, but I need to display for every IdPilota which point he reached in every championship.

```
atm the displayed data show 43 0 0 0 0 0 due to group  by IdPilota:
```

but I need to display the right point gained in every championship

There is a way to display what I need?

```
43 <- from (Montecarlo)
33 <- from (Sweden)
43 <- from (Mexico)
43 <- from (Argentina)
43 33 43 43
```

Hope to have explained what I need!

EDIT:
This is the working query atm:

```
    SELECT Id, totale, num_prove, IdPilota, Nome, Cognome, Team, Nazionalita, Plate, Classe, VetturaUsata, Penalita, PaPenalty, PuntiCarriera, PuntiCarrieraP,
SUM(PuntiMon), SUM(PuntiSve), SUM(PuntiMes), SUM(PuntiArg), SUM(PuntiPor), SUM(PuntiIta), SUM(PuntiPol), SUM(PuntiFin), SUM(PuntiGer), SUM(PuntiCin), SUM(PuntiFra), SUM(PuntiSpa), SUM(PuntiGrb), SUM(PuntiAus), RallyCorso,
SUM(PuntiMon) + SUM(PuntiSve) + SUM(PuntiMes) + SUM(PuntiArg) + SUM(PuntiPor) + SUM(PuntiIta) + SUM(PuntiPol) + SUM(PuntiFin) + SUM(PuntiGer) + SUM(PuntiCin) + SUM(PuntiFra) + SUM(PuntiSpa) + SUM(PuntiGrb) + SUM(PuntiAus) AS Punti
FROM temp_table_5975a9e73a835
GROUP BY IdPilota
ORDER BY Punti DESC;
```

Just to know if this is a correct way to display the data I need

Comment: Is 15  the number of the players?

Comment: Yes every query before this to populate the temp table have a limit 15 (Because the points are from 40 to 1). In the meantime if i add SUM() to every Puntixxx row i got the results i need.

This is the modified sql part:

SUM(PuntiMon), SUM(PuntiSve), SUM(PuntiMes), SUM(PuntiArg), SUM(PuntiPor), SUM(PuntiIta), SUM(PuntiPol), SUM(PuntiFin), SUM(PuntiGer), SUM(PuntiCin), SUM(PuntiFra), SUM(PuntiSpa), SUM(PuntiGrb), SUM(PuntiAus)

Comment: I don't understand when you say "this mean i have for each championship (Montecarlo, Sweden, Mexico and so on) 15 results inside the temp table. 15 for montecarlo 15 for sweden and so on"

If i read your query, i image your temp table have this columns:

IdPilota PuntiX PuntiY PuntiZ

and if 15 is the number of "Piloti", this table contains 15 rows, and not 15 for each championship.

Is it right?

Comment: i have 14 championship (http://www.realrally.com/wp-risultati/risultati.php)
Every Championship assign to the first 15 drivers xx points.
this mean when inserted into the temp table i have 210 results
15 for Montecarlo, 15 for Sweden and so on.

Before adding SUM(Puntixxx) to every row i only got the Driver Position and his total points Not the points for every championship he do.

Look at the link you can see the query in working stage. Just dunno if is the right way to do a complex query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you have specific restrictions or limitations but I do not usually mix business logic with presentation logic. In this case i would prefer don't create a temp table (maybe a view is better) because you use it in order to show a table on the presentation layer. 
I assume i have a data model like this (i repeat: i don't know if it is your case)

TABLE "PILOTI"

```
+--------+-------------+
|  ID    | NOME        |
+--------+-------------+
|   1    | Colin McRea |
+--------+-------------+
|   2    | Carlos Sainz|
+--------+-------------+
```

TABLE "GARE"

```
+--------+-------------+
|  ID    | NOME        |
+--------+-------------+
|   1    | Montecarlo  |
+--------+-------------+
|   2    | Argentina   |
+--------+-------------+
|   3    | Svezia      |
+--------+-------------+
```

TABLE "CAMPIONATO" (n-n => relation table between GARE and PILOTI)

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  ID    | ID_PILOTA   |  ID_GARA    | PUNTEGGIO   |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   1    |    1        |    1        |     43      |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   2    |    1        |    2        |     33      |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   3    |    2        |    1        |     15      |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   4    |    2        |    2        |     18      |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

With this query, i retrieve for each driver, the points reached every championship

```
SELECT P.NOME, G.NOME, C.PUNTEGGIO
FROM CAMPIONATO C
JOIN PILOTI P ON P.ID = C.ID_PILOTA
JOIN GARE   G ON G.ID = C.ID_GARA
```

You can add a "WHERE" condition in order to filter for a single driver (or single championship). 
For example, if you have 15 drivers, you can retrieve the points reached to each driver (for each championship) with only 15 query adding

```
WHERE P.ID = :id_pilota
```

to the prevoious query.

You may also create a view with this query and calculate the total points but i prefer to do this in PHP and not in MySQL. 
I.E. (PSEUDO-CODE)

```
foreach($driver){
 queryToGetPoints();
 foreach($championship){
   $totalPoints+=$points;
 }
 printHtmlRow();
}
```

However, With MySql the ordering is more simply

```
SELECT P.NOME,SUM(C.PUNTEGGIO) AS TOTALE
FROM CLASSIFICA C
JOIN  PILOTI P ON P.ID = C.ID_PILOTA
GROUP BY C.ID_PILOTA 
ORDER BY TOTALE ASC
```

In order to update the points, after a championship is closed, you can insert in "CAMPIONATO" table, for each driver, a new row whit his own ID, the ID of the championship and the points reached.

I.E.

```
INSERT INTO CAMPIONATO (ID_PILOTA, ID_GARA, PUNTEGGIO) VALUES (1,3,18)
```

=> McRea reached 18 points in Svezia

You may also create a table "CLASSIFICA" whit two fields: ID_PILOTA e TOTALE then create a trigger on "CAMPIONATO" table "after insert" in order to update the CAMPIONATO.TOTALE field with the sum of the old value + the points inserted.

So, you can see there is more than one way in order to do what you want.
My suggestion is: if one more query help you to get your code more simply, use it even if there is a computational overhead (multiple queries in nested loop in this case). 
Hope this help you. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The temp table is necessary due to complex query before gain all the data to make the latest query for final result.
We can meet by email i will send you the php code and the db .sql to let you understand better how many data i have to handle and play with.